# How to delegate events in Ext Js 6

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I've been trying to use delegates in Ext JS 6 to handle events instead of regular event handling. However, I was unable to find any resources on the topic.

to be more specific, I'm trying to make pressing the Enter button while on a form fire a button click event.

Could anyone please provide a demonstration on how they are used? Any code snippets or links would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What about this "delegate" feature in addListener? http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0-classic/Ext.mixin.Observable.html#method-addListener